# Rails 7: ActiveStorage Image Attachment from URL not Attaching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to get my Rails 7 app to attach an image from the URL.  It's on the `appearances#new` page, but obviously the logic is in my `appearances#create` method.

My `appearance.rb` model is pretty simple:

```
class Appearance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :support
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I've tested the attachment with a normal upload via form and it works perfectly, so I know that part is set up and functional.

I have the following code in my `appearances_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @appearance = Appearance.new(appearance_params)
    @support = Support.find(params[:appearance][:support_id])

    require 'open-uri'
    puts "NOW WE DO THE IMAGE THING"
    url = params[:appearance][:original_url]
    puts "THE URL IS: " + url
    retrieved_image = URI.open(url)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @appearance.save
        @appearance.image.attach(io: retrieved_image, filename: "#{ @support.name } (Support Photo).png", content_type: 'image/png')
        format.html { redirect_to support_path(@appearance.support) }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I run the create method, here's my server log:

```
20:46:47 web.1  | Processing by AppearancesController#create as TURBO_STREAM
20:46:47 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "appearance"=>{"support_id"=>"13", "original_url"=>"https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-sxVE79V7jX5cNf1A1hSUeIg5/user-mdH5MTlFfluKtgX1wPAfIY0q/img-FUPdjMwMbJXDg4K1WKH7qk1i.png?st=2023-12-30T03%3A46%3A35Z&se=2023-12-30T05%3A46%3A35Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2023-12-29T15%3A04%3A50Z&ske=2023-12-30T15%3A04%3A50Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=PtXswLQPqFMgWM9QKoIEyUg84y6pptuV2Y49Nn063i4%3D"}, "commit"=>"Choose Selected Appearance"}
20:46:47 web.1  |   Support Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "supports".* FROM "supports" WHERE "supports"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
20:46:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:30:in `create'
20:46:47 web.1  | NOW WE DO THE IMAGE THING
20:46:47 web.1  | THE URL IS: https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-sxVE79V7jX5cNf1A1hSUeIg5/user-mdH5MTlFfluKtgX1wPAfIY0q/img-FUPdjMwMbJXDg4K1WKH7qk1i.png?st=2023-12-30T03%3A46%3A35Z&se=2023-12-30T05%3A46%3A35Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2023-12-29T15%3A04%3A50Z&ske=2023-12-30T15%3A04%3A50Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=PtXswLQPqFMgWM9QKoIEyUg84y6pptuV2Y49Nn063i4%3D
20:46:48 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   Support Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "supports".* FROM "supports" WHERE "supports"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   Appearance Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "appearances" ("support_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "original_url") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["support_id", 13], ["created_at", "2023-12-30 04:46:48.184513"], ["updated_at", "2023-12-30 04:46:48.184513"], ["original_url", "https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-sxVE79V7jX5cNf1A1hSUeIg5/user-mdH5MTlFfluKtgX1wPAfIY0q/img-FUPdjMwMbJXDg4K1WKH7qk1i.png?st=2023-12-30T03%3A46%3A35Z&se=2023-12-30T05%3A46%3A35Z&sp=r&sv=2021-08-06&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=6aaadede-4fb3-4698-a8f6-684d7786b067&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2023-12-29T15%3A04%3A50Z&ske=2023-12-30T15%3A04%3A50Z&sks=b&skv=2021-08-06&sig=PtXswLQPqFMgWM9QKoIEyUg84y6pptuV2Y49Nn063i4%3D"]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  COMMIT
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 24], ["record_type", "Appearance"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 24], ["record_type", "Appearance"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "jt24gim7du6788omn4xgunewca31"], ["filename", "CJ (Support Photo).png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "local"], ["byte_size", 3147861], ["checksum", "tXWTXUFi0AojlD5e7NzGbQ=="], ["created_at", "2023-12-30 04:46:48.205310"]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "image"], ["record_type", "Appearance"], ["record_id", 24], ["blob_id", 299], ["created_at", "2023-12-30 04:46:48.207017"]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   Appearance Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "appearances" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "appearances"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2023-12-30 04:46:48.208926"], ["id", 24]]
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  COMMIT
20:46:48 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  |   Disk Storage (8.3ms) Uploaded file to key: jt24gim7du6788omn4xgunewca31 (checksum: tXWTXUFi0AojlD5e7NzGbQ==)
20:46:48 web.1  | [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: cdc07d55-f786-4cd4-b9db-a4dc0766a193) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00000001083668d0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://mhv2023/ActiveStorage::Blob/299>>
20:46:48 web.1  | [ActiveJob] ↳ app/controllers/appearances_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
20:46:48 web.1  | Redirected to http://localhost:5555/supports/13
20:46:48 web.1  | Completed 302 Found in 853ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 18184)
```

You can tell from the puts statements at the beginning that the url is furnishing properly (I've checked the url that is puts-ed and it opens to the appropriate picture.

However, something in either the `retrieved_image = URI.open(url)` or `@appearance.image.attach(io: retrieved_image, filename: "#{ @support.name } (Support Photo).png", content_type: 'image/png')` lines is messing up and the image is not getting attached.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?